# Eclipse executable launcher error: Exported Product is Unable to locate companion shared library

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, java-17

I have an Eclipse RCP Aplication, that was created using eclipse 3.7.

Now I'using last version on eclipse.

For the record, I don't convert the app to E4, I just modify some lines, and it works.

Also I'm using Java 17.

When I run from the Run or Debug from the menu, I can see the app.

So I want to Export the product, and everything looks fine.
But when I double click I get the error:

[image]

This is how I create the exported product
[image]

Please give me some advices on how to complete this task

best regards!

EDit:
added Agrotracker.product file
´´

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="AgroTracker" id="AgroTracker.product" application="AgroTracker.application" version="1.1.148.qualifier" type="features" includeLaunchers="true" autoIncludeRequirements="true">

   <aboutInfo>
      <image path="/AgroTracker/icons/cse_230x83.gif"/>
      <text>
         %aboutText
      </text>
   </aboutInfo>

   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgsWin>-console
      </programArgsWin>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages/>

   <splash
      startupProgressRect="5,5,400,20"
      startupMessageRect="7,25,400,20"
      startupForegroundColor="008040" />
   <launcher name="AgroTracker.exe">
      <win useIco="true">
         <ico path="/AgroTracker/icons/LogoKlein.ico"/>
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>


   <vm>
      <linux include="true">jre1.5.0_06</linux>
      <windows include="true">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-17</windows>
   </vm>


   <plugins>
      <plugin id="AgroTracker"/>
      <plugin id="ar.com.cse.cseagro.libraries"/>
      <plugin id="com.ibm.icu"/>
      <plugin id="javax.servlet"/>
      <plugin id="javax.xml"/>
      <plugin id="javax.xml.stream"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ant.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.compare.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.commands"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.expressions"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filebuffers"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.jobs"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.net"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.variables"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.app"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.help"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.text"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.rcp"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.text"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.carbon"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.forms"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.net"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.views"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.update.configurator"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.update.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.update.core.win32"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.update.scheduler"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.update.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.sat4j.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.sat4j.pb"/>
   </plugins>

   <features>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.rcp"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature"/>
      <feature id="AgroTracker.Feature"/>
   </features>

   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="4" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.update.configurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="4" />
      <property name="org.eclipse.update.reconcile" value="false" />
   </configurations>

   <repositories>
      <repository location="http://localhost/agrotracker-updates" name="" enabled="true" />
   </repositories>

   <preferencesInfo>
      <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
   </preferencesInfo>

   <cssInfo>
   </cssInfo>

</product>
```

´´

Comment: The only supported way to build an RCP now is to use [tag:tycho] (there is a tutorial [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)). Eclipse 3.7 is 13 years and 29 releases old, several things have changed in the configuration requirements for an RCP since then.

Comment: What greg-449 says. Something seems to be wrong in your `AgroTracker.product` which is missing in your question. Did you follow the [_Plug-in Migration Guide_](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/nav/2_3)?

Comment: There a couple of things that looks odd in your `AgroTracker.product`, e.g. `<plugin ... type="features" ...`, but `<plugins>` is not empty and `<linux include="true">jre1.5.0_06</linux>`. You might look how Eclipse does it: https://github.com/eclipse-packaging/packages/blob/master/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product/epp.product (with `<feature id="org.eclipse.justj.epp" installMode="root"/>` you include Java as a feature that can be updated)

Comment: There also look to be several 32 bit plugins in there which need to be replaced with 64 bit, there is even a macOS Carbon plugin which was obsolete long ago. As already mention you have plugin and feature - not sure what happens when you do that. Best to use just features which should pick up the correct plugins (you will need a feature for your own plugins)